# Postgresql insert trigger becomes slow when querying current table

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, plpgsql

When inserting a lot number into a table we are counting the number times the base number exists, and adding a -## to the end of the new number based on that count.

I have stripped out most the logic (we check for other things as well). I also am aware of the logic flaw here that would skip -1.

```sql
-- Function: stone._lsuniqueid()

-- DROP FUNCTION stone._lsuniqueid();

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION stone._lsuniqueid()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
 _count INTEGER;

BEGIN
  -- Obtain the number of occurences of this new ls_number
  SELECT COUNT(ls_number) into _count
  FROM ls
  WHERE ls_number LIKE CAST(NEW.ls_number || '%' AS text);

  -- Allow new ls_numbers to be entered as is, otherwise add "-#{count + 1}"
  -- to the end of the ls_number
  if _count > 0 THEN
    NEW.ls_number = NEW.ls_number || '-' || CAST(_count + 1 AS text);
  END IF;      

  RETURN NEW;
END
$BODY$

INSERT INTO ls VALUES (NEXTVAL('ls_ls_id_seq'),7285,UPPER('20151012'));
--> Query returned successfully: one row affected, 391 ms execution time.
```

The count query is plenty fast

```sql
SELECT COUNT(ls_number)
FROM ls
WHERE ls_number LIKE CAST('20151012' || '%' AS text);
--> 19ms
```

For comparison I tried a similar trigger, but ran the count against a different table with same amount of rows, and similar query time.

```sql
SELECT COUNT(lsdetail_id)
FROM lsdetail
WHERE lsdetail_id > 2433308
--> 20ms
```

Running the same insert with the count running against a different table returns the result 20 times faster.

```sql
INSERT INTO ls VALUES (NEXTVAL('ls_ls_id_seq'),7285,UPPER('20151012'));
 --> Query returned successfully: one row affected, 20 ms execution time.
```

The ls table has about 2.5 million rows

I've tried a couple of different things and the issue seems to be when selecting from the same table I'm inserting into.

I would like to know why this happening, but I would also be open to a better way to create "sub-lot" numbers.

Thanks!

Comment: #ToreyHeinz do you mean NEW.ls_number := NEW.ls_number || '-' || CAST(_count + 1 AS text) ? Is that a typo or are you missing the assignment component of the colon (:=)?

Comment: It could be unrelated but SELECT COUNT will return null not zero if it doesn't find the NEW.ls_number. Logic doesn't account for this case. Perhaps check for null prior to >0 check. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-aggregate.html

Comment: @FastEngy the assignment seems to work fine without colon notation, but now that you mention it, it does seem wrong. Maybe := is only required when assigning to a variable.

Comment: If _count is null then (_count > 0) will return null and not true.

Comment: What happens if you replace the whole block with NEW.ls_number = NEW.ls_number || COALESCE('-' || (SELECT COUNT(ls_number) FROM ls WHERE ls_number LIKE NEW.ls_number || '%') + 1, ''); It will always write over the NEW.ls_number value but it will get rid of the temp storage. Coalesce evaluates first non null entry. If the select count is null it will set that whole part to null and append the empty string.

Comment: Ps I think you're right on the variable assignment.

Comment: @FastEngy thanks looking into this!

Comment: These numbers look like dates to me. But you cast them into strings and perform a wildcard-search on them. Maybe this *problem* could be solved by doing date-arithmetic on date variables instead?

Comment: @joop The ls_number is just text. Sometimes a PO# may be used or a Lot# from the vendor. In this case the text used is simply the current date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer here:
http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/27705.1150381444@sss.pgh.pa.us

**Re: How to analyze function performance**

> "Mindaugas"  writes:
>
> > Is it possible to somehow analyze function performance? E.g. we are using function cleanup() which takes obviously too much time to execute but I have problems trying to figure what is slowing things down.
> >
> > When I explain analyze function lines step by step it show quite acceptable performance.

--

> Are you sure you are "explain analyze"ing the same queries the function
>   is really doing?  **You have to account for the fact that what plpgsql is
>   issuing is parameterized queries, and sometimes that limits the
>   planner's ability to pick a good plan**.  For instance, if you have

```
declare x int;
begin
    ...
    for r in select * from foo where key = x loop ...
```

> then what is really getting planned and executed is "select * from foo
>   where key = $1" --- every plpgsql variable gets replaced by a parameter
>   symbol "$n".  You can model this for EXPLAIN purposes with a prepared
>   statement:

```
prepare p1(int) as select * from foo where key = $1;
explain analyze execute p1(42);
```

> If you find out that a particular query really sucks when parameterized,
>   you can work around this by using EXECUTE to force the query to be
>   planned afresh on each use with literal constants instead of parameters:

Then I looked into this:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN

> **39.5.4. Executing Dynamic Commands**
>
> Oftentimes you will want to generate dynamic commands inside your PL/pgSQL functions, that is, commands that will involve different tables or different data types each time they are executed. **PL/pgSQL's normal attempts to cache plans for commands (as discussed in Section 39.10.2) will not work in such scenarios.** To handle this sort of problem, the EXECUTE statement is provided:

```
EXECUTE 'SELECT count(*) FROM mytable WHERE inserted_by = $1 AND inserted <= $2'
INTO c
USING checked_user, checked_date;
```

--

So in the end it was a matter of updating count select to this:

```
 EXECUTE 'SELECT COALESCE(COUNT(ls_number), 0) FROM ls WHERE ls_number LIKE $1 || ''%'';'
 INTO _count
 USING NEW.ls_number;
```

Comment: After  updating the count select to use `EXECUTE` the insert time dropped to 20ms.